# Populate a String Array dynamically

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to make an app for my parents business, but at this point I found a problem.

I'm trying to get some strings from a SQLite database and to store them into an array.

I'm trying this:

```
            //This opens the db
            SQLManager info = new SQLManager(this);
            info.open();              

            String[] data = {"", "", "", ""};

            for (int i = 1; i == 3; i++)
            {
                data[i]=(info.getProduct(i));
            }

            info.close();
            tv.setText(data[0]);
            tv.setText(data[1]);
            tv.setText(data[2]);
```

`info.getproduct` is a method which gets a string from the database. This works fine. The problem is that i can't update the value of the array. It always shows the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You Do This,

```
  String[] data = new String[4];

        for (int i = 0; i <data .length; i++)
        {
            data[i]=(info.getProduct(i));
        }
```

It Helps You.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in the `for` loop is supposed to work as a `while`-condition, meaning the loop will run while it is true, as `i` starts as 1 it will not be 3 and thus the loop terminates at once. 
You probably want a loop that looks like this:

```
for( int i = 1; i<=3; i++ ){ //Are you sure you want to start from 1? The first element in an array has index 0.
    //Loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do this

```
String[] data = {"", "", "", ""};

            for (int i = 0; i <data .length; i++)
            {
                data[i]=(info.getProduct(i));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

this loop will never run you should change it to:

```
for(int i =0;i<3;i++){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the use of for loop is like this

```
for(initializatin;condition;increment)
```

while in your case it is not condition it is a statement, so work on it.

you can change to `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)`

Answer (score -1):

not i==3, use i<3 in the for loop